# In Windows Explorer (set to detailed format), can I change the color of some file names?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Several months ago, I accidently changed the color of some file names to blue in Windows Explorer. Now, I'd like to do that with a purpose. But I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 2):

Blue file names indicate you've compressed the files via the NTFS filesystem. To compress or decompress files, go into their property sheet, and under the Advanced attributes button is the option to compress or not.  You can also choose to encrypt files, which would display their file names in green text.

The tool [Folder Marker](http://www.foldermarker.com/folder-marker-free.php) can allow you to change the color of folder icons without compressing or encrypting them, but it does not change files nor does it change the text color.